# Javascript randomly stopped working

Tags: javascript, html

I can't get my Javascript to execute.It randomly stopped working yesterday and I've been messing around to try to get it to work. I tried making a simple code to see if it would work but, I have no luck. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js\hello.js"></script>
<form id="hello" onsubmit="return hello();">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Javascript (in sub folder called js):

```
function hello()
{
    alert("HELLO");
    return false;
}
```

It's really annoying me because all of my Javascript codes aren't working but they were working perfectly fine yesterday. I am not sure what happened...

I meant to make an alert I was just wasn't thinking. It still doesn't work anyways. It's like it isn't even calling the function.

Comment: are you confusing JavaScript with shell script / batch files?

Comment: Is the line `echo "HELLO";` alright?

Comment: Post also the _actual_ code that was failing, which prompted you to write this faulty test code.

Comment: Always develop JavaScript with your browser's error console open.  If something is failing, you will see errors reported there.

Comment: How do I open the browser's error console?

Comment: Ctl-Shift-i in Chrome, F12 in IE, developer tools available in the menus of all modern browsers.

Answer (score 2):

use `alert("HELLO");` instead of echo.  echo is PHP not javascript.

If you want to output to a speicific tag then use `document.getElementById("idOfTag").innerHTML = "HELLO";`